# Finding a string inside a string twice as big effectively

Tags: java, arrays, search

I'm looking to see if the difference between every adjacent number in an array is the same as another array, or a rotation of it, for example

```
A = {1,2,4}, so the differences are {1,1,2}
B = {4,6,7}, the differences are {1,2,1}
```

If all elements in {1,2,1} were moved clockwise one-element, the result is {1,1,2}, which is correct.

so far I convert the differences to strings, and then see if the differences of the second array is found in the first concatenated with itself

```
valid if "1 2 1" is in "1 1 2 1 1 2"
```

my code so far looks like this
        count is the length of the array, both have the same length

```
    int c = count - 1;
    StringBuilder b1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder b2 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        b1.append(array1[i + 1] - array1[i]);
        b1.append(" ");
        b2.append(array2[i + 1] - array2[i]);
        b2.append(" ");
    }
    b1.append((array1[0] - array1[c]) + d);
    b1.append(" ");
    b2.append((array2[0] - array2[c]) + d);

    String a2 = b2.toString();
    String a3 = b1.toString() + b1.toString();

    System.out.println(a3.contains(a2) ? "valid" : "not valid"); //bottleneck here
```

My problem is when I use big arrays (up to about 250,000 elements) I get a massive bottleneck at the last line with the .contains(). I'm wondering if there is either a faster way of check if its inside the method than what I'm using, or if I can check while building up the string, or if there is a completely different way of doing this?

Comment: "rotate shift {1,2,1}...." is an incorrect statement - you wanted to phrase it like - "If I moved the elements one position clockwise". Rotate shift is a very different beast. Edited the post.

Comment: "A String inside a String" also known as String-ception.

Comment: Did you try using `Short` instead of String? The reason is that you seem to have only single digits in your array - so you could probably deal with `Short` rather than converting to String? I suppose you tried with `Integer` and failed already due to the such big array size? May be `Short` will make a difference. Also, you can probably use `ArrayList<>` to save the differences in there using indices. Then you can get them out in order.

Comment: the numbers could be between 0 and half a million

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a more efficient algorithm then the one that is used in `contains` method(it actually depends on a concrete implementation, but it looks like it is not efficient in the version of Java you are using).
You can use Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm. It has linear time and space complexity in the worst case so it works fast even for very big arrays. Note that there is no need to convert an array to a string, because this algorithm works for arrays, too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it more, I tried implementing the pseudocode but I couldn't get it to give me the correct answer when I tried it with arrays